# Rhythmbox - Can't add music from other harddrive to playlist

Tags: rhythmbox

All of my music is located on another hard drive. I've set the Rhythmbox library location to my music folder in the other hd and it's all shown just fine in the "Music" part of rhythmbox. But it doesn't work if I try to create a playlist and drag some tracks into it. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

It works with any track I transfer in the same hard drive where my Ubuntu installation resides. But I can't actually transfer all my music on it since I don't have that much space on this particular hard drive.

Comment: and..you're using ubuntu 14.04? I'm able to drag music from Music library to new playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I store my music in a separate drive as well.  Go to the Music part.  Select the song you want to add. Click `Edit -> Add to Playlist`.  The default is New Playlist.  You can rename it after you add the first song.  Go to the next song, click `Edit > Add to Playlist`.  This time the playlist you created for the first song should be an option.  Add it there.  Keep doing this until you have the songs you want.

Comment: @wittich  Thanks for the edit.  I'm glad some can read typonese.